# Div pushing other div's

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't get the `transitioning` to work for a `div` using `positioning relative` and using jQuery to set css to `left -50px`. See fiddle for better explanation :).

Does the transitioning not work for positioning settings? anyone other solutions to make the picture div slide inside/below it's parents div?

Thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/hde2ts30/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML needs some brushing up.

You've got three different elements with an ID of `picture`.  An ID is intended to be unique on a page.  Because you added those extra ID elements, you were applying the transition to the wrong elements.

Your updated HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="picture_container">
    <div id="picture">
        <img class="picture" src="http://omgdgt.com/images/04042014/website-of-the-day-jsfiddle-written-by-web-developers-for-web-developers-0.jpg" />
        <img class="picture" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-desktop-1440x900-a.png" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Your updated CSS looks like this:

```
#picture_container{
    width:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#picture{
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    left: 0;
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block; 
}
.picture{
    width: 20px;   
}
```

What we're doing here is applying the transition to the picture sliding container as opposed to all three elements at once.  And since the "left" transform is only applied to the div, then you're only sliding that and leaving the pictures static within their container.

**BUT HERE'S THE IMPORTANT PART:  Transitions don't occur without a starting state**

So because your container didn't have a `left` value to begin with, it had *nothing* to transition from.  So it just jumps to `left:-20px` because it's the only value it has to calculate from.

**In order for transitions to work, a value needs both an *initial* state and an *end* state**

Comment: Didn't know transitions don't occur without a starting state, sounds logical though. Worked like a charm, thanks for the detailled info! Still learning something new everyday haha (y)

Answer (score 2):

You should change it to `.css('.margin-left', '-50px');` in the JS

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hde2ts30/7/)

Comment: You can do it with `left`, too. Just specify the initial `left` position: http://jsfiddle.net/hde2ts30/8/